# Generated Id always 0

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have declared my entity's Id:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="integer") @ORM\GeneratedValue
 */
 protected $id;
```

But everytime I try to save it my database after a form, I get '0', which consequently gives : `Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'`

My storage logic is the following:

```
public function CallManager($data) 
    {
    $callRequested= new CallRequested;
    $callRequested-> setClientContact($data['clientContact']);
    $callRequested-> setProvider($data['provider']);
    $callRequested-> setCallCenter($data['callCenterContact']);
    $whenCall= $data['schedule'];
    $language= $data['language'];
    $date = new \DateTime();
    $callRequested-> setRequestTime($date);

    var_dump($data);

    $this->entityManager->persist($callRequested);
    $this->entityManager->flush();

    }
```

What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure that one line of code is going to help others to understand your  problem and give you the correct solution. We are not NECROMANCER here. Please provide more details. [Read how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell it that you want it to auto-increment like so:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;
```

Comment: I had that before, and still the same problem, tried with also with sequence (does not work) and identity

Comment: As you were playing around with this, did you reflect these changes to the DB? All this gets ultimately converted to SQL CREATE / ALTER queries if I'm not mistaken. You can check if it's reflected by looking at the table in the DB, specifically the setup of the ID field. It should have auto increment set and be an appropriate numeric type etc

Comment: We'll need more info in that case I think. Could you add the full entity and the DB structure to your question?

Comment: I've found the mistake, it was not set for 'auto increment'.

Comment: Great, you should check out [migrations](https://github.com/doctrine/migrations) - this should allow you to have doctrine compare your entities and your datasource structure and generate as well as execute the corresponding commands to ensure that both stay in sync. In other words - migrations automate the datasource management so you only have to focus on your entities and can avoid mistakes like this one.